# Change color of active button among multiple buttons in React using material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the color only of a button, which is clicked. And by default the first button to be active. The problem that I have is that in Material UI when I use Button there is a span so I cannot use e.target.name ... because there is no name in the span. This span is created when I type some text between the button tags => Some title. As well I intend to have some other actions when the button is clicked, except that it should change its color to show, which one is active.
If there is some way around I will appreciate it. Down below is some code, that I tried, but I do not know what to do in clickedButtonHandler and if it's possible to pass any argument on it when the button is clicked... for example the name.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Container, Box, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const StyledButton = withStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    marginRight: "1rem",
    width: "25%",
    padding: "1rem",
    fontSize: "1.2rem",
    borderRadius: "1rem",
    color: "#000",
    fontWeight: "400",
    textTransform: "capitalize"
  }
}))(Button);

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  buttonContainerWrapper: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "#ccc",
    border: "1px solid #000",
    padding: "1rem",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  },
  lastButtonFilter: {
    marginRight: "0rem"
  },
  activeButton: {
    background: "#fc7303",
    color: "#fff"
  }
}));

export default function Filter() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = useState({
    first: true,
    second: false,
    third: false,
    fourth: false
  });

  const clickedButtonHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target);
    const { name } = e.target;
    setActiveButton(name);
    console.log(activeButton);
  };

  return (
    <Container className={classes.buttonContainerWrapper}>
      <Box className={classes.buttonContainer}>
        <StyledButton
          name="button-one"
          className={activeButton?.first ? `${classes.activeButton}` : ""}
          onClick={clickedButtonHandler}
        >
          Button One
        </StyledButton>
        <StyledButton
          name="button-two"
          className={
            activeButton?.second ? `${classes.activeButton}` : ""
          }
          onClick={clickedButtonHandler}
        >
          Button Two
        </StyledButton>
        <StyledButton
          name="button-three"
          className={activeButton?.third ? `${classes.activeButton}` : ""}
          onClick={clickedButtonHandler}
        >
          Button Three
        </StyledButton>
        <StyledButton
          name="button-four"
          className={
            activeButton?.fourth ? `${classes.activeButton}` : ""
          }
          onClick={clickedButtonHandler}
        >
          Button Four
        </StyledButton>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

here is the link to codepan: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-sinoussi-u3o3s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for targetting the root element use the [`ButtonBase`](https://material-ui.com/api/button-base/) component.
And also to keep track of active buttons in `useState`, spread the old state first and then update the new value of the new variable (might differ in different use case or requirement). I've updated that issue.

```
export default function Filter() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = useState('first');

  const clickedButtonHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target);
    const { name } = e.target;
    setActiveButton(name);
    console.log(activeButton);
  };

  return (
    <Container className={classes.buttonContainerWrapper}>
      <Box className={classes.buttonContainer}>
        <StyledButton
          name="first"
          className={activeButton === "first" ? `${classes.activeButton}` : ""}
          onClick={clickedButtonHandler}
        >
          Button One
        </StyledButton>
        <StyledButton
          name="second"
          className={activeButton === "second" ? `${classes.activeButton}` : ""}
          onClick={clickedButtonHandler}
        >
          Button Two
        </StyledButton>
        <StyledButton
          name="third"
          className={activeButton === "third" ? `${classes.activeButton}` : ""}
          onClick={clickedButtonHandler}
        >
          Button Three
        </StyledButton>
        <StyledButton
          name="fourth"
          className={activeButton === "fourth" ? `${classes.activeButton}` : ""}
          onClick={clickedButtonHandler}
        >
          Button Four
        </StyledButton>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Workign demo:-
[image: Edit white-rain-ye62u]

Comment: Working fine, but how should I make it only the clicked button to change its color, so the other to remain with their default color. What I mean when I click the next button the previous one to become white again

Comment: ohh, then just store the name of the clicked button and then check the activestate while giving className. I've updated the answer...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can also loop through an array for the buttons

```
export default function Filter() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = useState("button-one");

  const clickedButtonHandler = (name) => {
    setActiveButton(name);
  };


  const buttons = ["button-one", "button-two", "button-three", "button-four"];

  return (
    <Container className={classes.buttonContainerWrapper}>
      <Box className={classes.buttonContainer}>
        {buttons.map((name) => (
          <StyledButton
            name={name}
            className={activeButton === name ? `${classes.activeButton}` : ""}
            onClick={() => clickedButtonHandler(name)}
          >
            {name}
          </StyledButton>
        ))}
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```